# Ext Form Model load two fields with same data

Tags: extjs

I have a Ext Model for Form. I need to load a single data value from password field to both password and confirm password field. Is it possible to load records like that in EXT?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. When a record is [loaded](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-loadRecord) in a form, the data is obtained by simply calling `getData()` on the record. Therefore, you can tweak your model to provide a copy of the password in another field like this:

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'id',
        'name',
        'password'
    ],
    getData: function() {
        var data = this.callParent(arguments);
        data['confirm_password'] = data['password'];
        return data;
    }
});
```

Full example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pgr

ALTERNATIVE APPROACH

If you do not want to change the model, then get the Password field mirror its value to the Confirm Password field whenever value is set through `setValue`:

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            name: 'name'
        },
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
            setValue: function(value) {
                this.superclass.setValue.apply(this, arguments);
                this.up('form').down('#confirm_password').setValue(value);
            },
            //inputType: 'password',
            name: 'password',
        },
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Confirm Password',
            //inputType: 'password',
            name: 'confirm_password',
            itemId: 'confirm_password'
        }
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
})
```

Full example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pgt